# Is this piecewise function a valid function?

Tags: functions

I think it isn't because for x = 2 and x = 4, h(x) is not defined. Is that right?

[image]

Comment: What does "valid" mean to you here?  You are correct that it is undefined for $x\in \{2,4\}$.

Comment: Agreed, yes. This would be fine if the domain were $\Bbb{R} \setminus \{2, 4\}$ instead, but since the domain is very clearly marked as $\Bbb{R}$, you would expect a well-defined value at $x = 2$ and $x = 4$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not a valid function, because despite the domain being indicated to be $\mathbb{R},$ there is no element $y$ in the codomain such that $(2,y)\in{h}$ and the same is true for $(4,y).$